# No viable conversion when iterating over string set

Tags: c++

Given the set:

{"alarm", "alert", "issue"}

I would like the output:

```
alarm
alert
issue
```

I would like to print each element of the set, backwards or forwards. Below is the code that I have attempted far:

```
set<string> str_set = {"hi", "bye", "there"}; string cur_word;

for(long iter = str_set.begin(); iter!= set.end(); iter++) {
    cout << iter << endl;
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
No viable conversion from 'std::__1::set<std::__1::basic_string<char>,
   std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char> >, 
std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >::iterator' (aka 
'__tree_const_iterator<std::__1::basic_string<char>, 
std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::basic_string<char>, void *> *, long>') to 
'long'
```

Comment: `iter!= set.end()` -> `iter!= str_set.end()`

Comment: Why is `iter` a `long`?

Comment: `long` -> `auto`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for your input! What does your code do differently?

Comment: @0x499602D2 yeah good question...I was just very confused on how to actually print an element in a set. I was thinking of using long to iterate through each element.

Comment: @Dracep Mine compiles. Yours does not.

Comment: @RetiredNinja ah I see that I wasn't consistent with my variable names. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the iterator returned by `std::set<std::string>::begin()` is being converted to `long` time.
You should define the type of `iter` as either `std::set<std::string>::iterator` or `auto`.

---

```
std::set<std::string> str_set = {"hi", "bye", "there"};
for(auto iter = str_set.begin(); iter != str_set.end(); iter++) {
    std::cout << *iter << '\n';
}
```

with `auto` being equivalent to `std::set<std::string>::iterator`.

---

OR

```
std::set<std::string> str_set = {"hi", "bye", "there"};
for(auto &value : str_set) {
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

with `auto` being equivalent to `std::string&`.

Comment: It would be best to explain what changed and why it was necessary to change. You should typically prefer pre-increment to post-increment with iterators, but it's not really a big deal here or for the purpose of this answer

Comment: thank you! This was very infromative and I learned that I can re-iterate over a set.